# Contexto do componente do vue esta vindo errado

Tags: vue.js, vue.js-2, vue-router

Estou com um problema no desenvolvimento de um projeto utilizando em Vue2, quando busco o contexto do componente, ele não me retorna o contexto "certo", como por exemplo o:

> $router

que se quer aparece no contexto que vem, o objeto que recebo quando busco é o seguinte:

```
{"a":{"staticRenderFns":[],"_compiled":true,"_scopeId":"data-v-4c198e4e","beforeCreate":[null,null],"__file":"src\\components\\Calendar.vue","beforeDestroy":[null],"_Ctor":{}}}
```

e assim não estou conseguindo fazer a manipulação de rotas sem o refresh do sistema por exemplo.
OBS: pode ser alguma atualização do ultimo meio ano, trabalhava com VUE em novembro e dezembro, mas janeiro troquei de emprego e nesse meio tempo não consegui acompanhar muito o desempenho do framework infelizmente.

desde já agradeço a ajuda.